# How to build wix toolset project?

Tags: visual-studio, wix

I've installed Wix Toolset 3.11.0.1528 and extension for VS 2015 0.9.17.13693

After pressing `build` I get:

> The WiX Toolset v4 build tools must be installed to build this project. To download WiX Toolset v4 visit ...

I don't get it. I have version 3.11 installed and it wants v4. I don't want to build anything from source.

What should I do to make it use available WiX version?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ah. Ok. At VS project manager (or whatever they call it), when you add `New project`, you have two almost identical choices:

- Setup project - A project for creating an MSI file
- Setup project - A project fro creating a WiX based XML MSI file

So the first one uses `<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi" ...`

And the second one: `<Wix xmlns="http://wixtoolset.org/schemas/v4/wxs" ...`

The second one fails. And just changing this url doesn't help.

Choose the first variant and just use it.

Answer (score 5):

Bit of a necro post but if anyone finds it helpful, well then, good.

Edit the XML as pointed out above by replacing the namespace from v4 to the v3 one.

```
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi"/>
```

Then edit the proj file of your setup and remove the reference to the WIX target path.

```
<WixTargetsPath Condition=" '$(WixTargetsPath)' == '' ">$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\WiX Toolset\v4\wix.targets</WixTargetsPath>
```

Finally, replace the import and target tags with the 3.11 version of the code.

```
    <Import Project="$(WixTargetsPath)" Condition=" '$(WixTargetsPath)' != '' " />
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\WiX\v3.x\Wix.targets" Condition=" '$(WixTargetsPath)' == '' AND Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\WiX\v3.x\Wix.targets') " />
  <Target Name="EnsureWixToolsetInstalled" Condition=" '$(WixTargetsImported)' != 'true' ">
    <Error Text="The WiX Toolset v3.11 (or newer) build tools must be installed to build this project. To download the WiX Toolset, see http://wixtoolset.org/releases/" />
  </Target>
```

Comment: Necro?  maybe.  Informative?  Definitely!  Thanks for the dive into the differences.